# All Subs Unsubscribe Reason Says "SalesForce version 5 Sync"

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, marketing-cloud-connect, unsubscribe, preference-center

Some subscribers in our account are having their Unsubscribe Reason set as: "SalesForce
version 5 Sync". I am having difficulty in replicating the behaviour to uncover what series of events or steps leads to this change taking place.

Under what scenarios is this "Sync" applying updates to SFMC All Subscribers?

My hunch was the "*Marketing Cloud Resubscribe*" & "*Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe*" buttons may cause this? However, we do not use those buttons. How else can MarketingCloudConnect automatically update SFMC?

When using LogUnsubEvent API, this will automatically set `PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail` field to true. This is out-of-the-box functionality of MCConect. This shouldn't be an issue because automation studio SQL checks our custom boolean field to generate a file to import to AllSubscribers. Is there any concern here?

**Setting the scene with Background Context:**

- Salesforce CRM with Person Accounts and Marketing Cloud Connect.
- We use a custom boolean field on the Person Account to manage email consent.
- In CRM, the MarketingCloudConnect "*Marketing Cloud Resubscribe*" & "*Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe*" buttons are removed from the page layout and we do not use them.
- SFMC has multiple BU's - all with "*Unsubscribe from this Business Unit only*" setting.
- Hourly automation setup to keep SFMC and CRM email opt-out in synchronisation.
- Custom Preference Center CloudPage that when processing unsubscribes does:

  - updates CRM via AMPscript to update our Custom boolean field, and
  - updates AllSubscribers via the LogUnsubEvent API

**Example All Subs Record:**

[image: All Subscribers Screenshot]

I have noticed that this issue is showing up when the subscriber record has ADD METHOD == **`SalesforceSubscriber`**. I ran the below query and checked the resulting subscriberKeys and did a look up to the AllSubs table. Sure enough, they have unsubReason as "*SalesForce version 5 Sync*" .... around 3k of them from the last month.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM 
    _ListSubscribers 
WHERE 1=1
    AND AddedBy = '-1000'
    AND AddMethod = 'Unknown'
    AND SubscriberType = 'ExactTarget'
    AND DateUnsubscribed >= CONVERT(DATE, '2023-04-01')
```

Comment: The `LogUnsubEvent` has a parameter call "Reason" for the reason the subscriber is being unsubscribed. I guess there is an automation doing the synchronization based on the custom boolean field for email consent in MC

Comment: Can you chcek the audit trail for this particular contact in sales cloud? You have the unsub date and the unsub originated in the crm so I’d investigate there